# using form action to post data to another domain

Tags: php, post, cross-domain

I tied to send variables to another domain by using form action and it works:

```
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/index.php?email=FOO&subject=BAR">
```

In the www.example.com/index.php, it is possible print out data with:

```
print_r($_GET);
>Array ( [email] => FOO [subject] => BAR )
```

However, when I try to reach data with print_r($_POST) command in www.example.com/index.php, I get an array without values:

```
print_r($_POST);
Array ( [email] => [subject] => )
```

You may suggest using only get method or any other method, but I wonder why the post method does not work for the same pattern.

Comment: The way you have used the form method and the way you define form action is wrong. You are getting value from $_GET because email and subject is passed as a URL string. Whatever is appended as url string you can that value with $_GET. 
Also when you use post method it never append a value as a url string in URL.

Comment: Thank you Yogs for the comment. But, still I can get the keys of the data array through the URL string with print_r($_POST) command:  Array ( [email] => [subject] => ) . It seems strange to me.